# Access Plugin data from Functions.php

Tags: functions

I'm trying to insert data from a wordpress post into a new table database table rather than `WP_postmeta`. My function is working, It'll insert the `$postid` no problem at all. The issues I'm having is I need to inser the latitude and longitude coordinates from Marty Spellerbergs 'Address Geocoder' Plugin.

On the plugin page, Marty says you can access the cooridnates inside the loop using these:

```
<?php echo get_geocode_lng( $post->ID ); ?>
<?php echo get_geocode_lat( $post->ID ); ?>
```

Now I know being inside the functions.php file, we are not actually inside the lood, so I've tried lots of different ways of accessing this data but I just can't do it. Is there a way to edit those lines specified by Marty so they can be called in the functions?.

This is one of my many many attempts at this:

```
function save_lat_lng( $post_id )   
{  
    global $wpdb;  

global $post;
$custom_lat = $_POST[get_geocode_lat( $post->ID )]; 
$custom_lng = $_POST[get_geocode_lng( $post->ID )];
// Check that we are editing the right post type  
if ( 'festival-event' != $_POST['post_type'] ) 
{  
    return;  
}  

// Check if we have a lat/lng stored for this property already  
$check_link = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM lat_lng_post WHERE post_id = '" . $post_id . "'");  
if ($check_link != null)   
{  
    // We already have a lat lng for this post. Update row  
    $wpdb->update(   
    'lat_lng_post',   
    array(   
        "lat" => $custom_lat,
        "lng" => $custom_lng 
    ),   
    array( 'post_id' => $post_id ),   
    array(   
        '%f',  
        '%f'  
    )  
    );  
}  
else  
{  
    // We do not already have a lat lng for this post. Insert row  
    $wpdb->insert(   
    'lat_lng_post',   
    array(   
        'post_id' => $post_id,  
        "lat" => $custom_lat,
        "lng" => $custom_lng
    ),   
    array(   
        '%d',   
        '%f',  
        '%f'  
    )   
    );  
}  
}  
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_lat_lng' )
```

Comment: Try replacing `$post->ID` with `get_the_ID()`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off in a few places. I'll try and let the code explain:

```
function wpse_199498_meta_to_table( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Use the second argument of our hook, which is the post object
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'festival-event' )
        return;

    global $wpdb;

    // Don't need to use $_POST, just use the functions as documented
    $custom_lat = get_geocode_lat( $post_id );
    $custom_lng = get_geocode_lng( $post_id );

    $check_link = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post WHERE post_id = %d", // Here's that missing comma!
            $post_id
        )
    );

    if ( $check_link ) {
        $wpdb->update(
            'lang_lng_post',
            array(   
                'lat' => $custom_lat,
                'lng' => $custom_lng,
            ),   
            array(
                'post_id' => $post_id,
            ),   
            array(   
                '%f',  
                '%f',
            ),
            '%d'
        );
    } else {
        $wpdb->insert(
            'lang_lng_post',
            array(   
                'post_id' => $post_id,
                'lat'     => $custom_lat,
                'lng'     => $custom_lng,
            ),   
            array(  
                '%d',
                '%f',  
                '%f',
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action(
    'wp_insert_post',            // Later than "save_post", will ensure plugin has already saved meta at this point
    'wpse_199498_meta_to_table',
    10,                          // Default priority
    2                            // Number of arguments
);
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, I really appreciate it, however, it caused a fatal error on the site, and left with a white screen

Comment: [Debug, debug, debug](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). Set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in your `wp-config.php`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know about that, anyway, it says the issue is with this section `$check_link = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post WHERE post_id = %d"
            $post_id
        )
    );`

Comment: Ahh, we're just missing a comma to separate the arguments - see revision.

Comment: There was also an extraneous comma further down, best to copy the whole code again.

Comment: There's no more errors, however it doesn't insert/add to the db table, Before the $post_id was adding, now nothing

Comment: Put an `exit;` inside the end of the function - run again and you'll probably see the error why (without the exit, WordPress redirects back to the edit screen and you're none the wiser)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but someone offered a solution on another forum which solved it, I'll post it as answer but I'll upvote you for your time, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer was given me to elsewhere, however thought i'd share just in case anyone has similar issues:

```
function save_lat_lng( $post_id )   
{  
    global $wpdb;  


global $post;
$custom_lat = get_geocode_lat( $post_id ); 
$custom_lng = get_geocode_lng( $post_id );
// Check that we are editing the right post type  
if ( 'festival-event' != $_POST['post_type'] ) 
{  
    return;  
}  


// Check if we have a lat/lng stored for this property already  
$check_link = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM lat_lng_post WHERE post_id = '" . $post_id . "'");  
if ($check_link != null)   
{  
    // We already have a lat lng for this post. Update row  
    $wpdb->update(   
    'lat_lng_post',   
    array(   
        "lat" => $custom_lat,
        "lng" => $custom_lng 
    ),   
    array( 'post_id' => $post_id ),   
    array(   
        '%f',  
        '%f'  
    )  
    );  
}  
else  
{  
    // We do not already have a lat lng for this post. Insert row  
    $wpdb->insert(   
    'lat_lng_post',   
    array(   
        'post_id' => $post_id,  
        "lat" => $custom_lat,
        "lng" => $custom_lng 
    ),   
    array(   
        '%d',   
        '%f',  
        '%f'  
    )   
    );  
}  
}  
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_lat_lng', 100 );
```

Also a massive thank you to @TheDeadMedic for spending so much time trying to help me.